# Where can i download the sharepoint manager 2013 tool?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Since codeplex is down, where can I download the SharePoint Manager 2013 tool? 
I tried to go to http://sp.codeplex.com, but its down.

Is there any other location where i can download SP Manager 2013 version?

Answer (score 11):

You are using wrong URL. Try to use this url http://spm.codeplex.com/

Comment: It should be noted that in downloaded file you should go to releases folder and then highest number of subfolder (7 at the time of writing) and then rename guid file name into zip file so you can unzip it.

Comment: In addition to Slaven's comment, the releases folder contains a releaseList.json file that details each of the releases

Answer (score 3):

Since CodePlex is down, here is an updated location to download 2013 and 2010 version:
https://github.com/keutmann/SPM/releases

Comment: There are several Github mirrors of SPM. This one seems to be best managed. An additional note as it had me chasing my tail for awhile: this tool must be run from the sharepoint server itself. It's not meant for remote management. And finally, the codeplex [issues & discussion pages](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=spm) still have much useful info.

Answer (score 2):

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=spm
The above link is working, they have archived that old site.

Comment: https://github.com/lexam79/SPM